# unable share data across the controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller, factory

I am building a SPA with angular and I have two controllers, and want to share data within them. using service/factory i am unable to share data. bellow is the codes.

```js
/*this service is a helper to submit multipart form data*/
appDls.service('multipartForm', ['$http', function($http){
  this.post = function(url,data){
    var responseVar = "";
    var fd = new FormData;
    for(var key in data){ 
      fd.append(key,data[key]);
    }
    return $http.post(url,fd,{
      transformRequest: angular.indentity,
      headers: {'Content-Type':undefined}
    });
  }
}]);

/*this factory is for sharing data across controllers*/

appDls.factory('sharedFactory', function(){
  var dataTobeShared = {};
  var interface = {};

  interface.add = function(d){dataTobeShared = d;}
  interface.put = function(){return dataTobeShared;}

  return interface;
});



/*this controller is for the main portal user redirection and portal rendering*/
appDls.controller('DlsappController', ['$scope', '$state','multipartForm','sharedFactory', function($scope,$state,multipartForm,sharedFactory){

  $scope.login = function(){
    var url = "../scripts/routes.php/authen";
    multipartForm.post(url,$scope.login).then(function(d){
      $scope.data = d.data;
    }); 
    $scope.data = sharedFactory.add;
    $scope.data = {};
  }
    
}]);


/*this controller is for landing page routing*/
appDls.controller('landingController', ['$scope', '$state','multipartForm','sharedFactory', function($scope,$state,multipartForm,sharedFactory){
  $scope.fucking = sharedFactory.put;
}]);
```

Please, let me know what is wrong in the above code...I am looking for a early reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think `$scope.data = sharedFactory.add;` will not add data
so use

```
sharedFactory.add($scope.data)
```

It will be great if you can share a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use need to correct calling functions in your controller

```
sharedFactory.add($scope.data);
sharedFactory.put();
```

```js
var appDls = angular.module('myCtrl', []);
/*this service is a helper to submit multipart form data*/
appDls.service('multipartForm', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    this.post = function(url, data) {
      var responseVar = "";
      var fd = new FormData;
      for (var key in data) {
        fd.append(key, data[key]);
      }
      return $http.post(url, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.indentity,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': undefined
        }
      });
    }
  }
]);

/*this factory is for sharing data across controllers*/

appDls.factory('sharedFactory', function() {
  var dataTobeShared = {};
  var interface = {};

  interface.add = function(d) {
    dataTobeShared = d;
  }
  interface.put = function() {
    return dataTobeShared;
  }

  return interface;
});



/*this controller is for the main portal user redirection and portal rendering*/
appDls.controller('DlsappController', ['$scope', 'multipartForm', 'sharedFactory',
  function($scope, multipartForm, sharedFactory) {

    //$scope.login = function(){
    // var url = "../scripts/routes.php/authen";
    // multipartForm.post(url,$scope.login).then(function(d){
    $scope.data = {
      "Name": "No One"
    };
    // }); 
    sharedFactory.add($scope.data);
    
    //}

  }
]);


/*this controller is for landing page routing*/
appDls.controller('landingController', ['$scope', 'multipartForm', 'sharedFactory',
  function($scope, multipartForm, sharedFactory) {
    $scope.fucking = sharedFactory.put();
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="DlsappController">
    DATA(DlsappController):{{data}}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="landingController">
    DATA(landingController):{{fucking}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!!